# Pass Boolean variable to Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck with an issue about passing a boolean variable to Google Maps API options. Here is my HTML

```html
<label for='zoom_scroll'>
                    <select name="zoom_scroll">

                    <option value='false' <?php selected( get_option('zoom_scroll'),'false'); ?> >No</option> 
                    <option value='true' <?php selected( get_option('zoom_scroll'),'true'); ?> >Yes</option>
                </select>
                </label>
```

Now I am passing data to JS file.Here is the snippet

```php
function call_params(){
        $script_params = array(

        'option_Map_Lat' => get_option('maps_lattitude'),
        'option_Map_lng' => get_option('maps_longitude'),
        'option_zoom_level' => get_option('zoom_level'),
        'option_Map_type' => get_option('maps_type'),
        'option_Scroll' => get_option('zoom_scroll')


    );

    wp_localize_script( 'demo', 'scriptParams', $script_params );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'demo' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_params', 200);
```

Following is a part of the maps options

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"), {
    zoom: parseInt(scriptParams.option_zoom_level), // this one is working
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[scriptParams.option_Map_type],
    scrollwheel: parseInt(scriptParams.option_Scroll), // this one is not working
    center: latlng,
    zoomControl:false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
});
```

While all other variables are being passed and interpreted, only the Boolean value for the scrollwheel is not working. Not sure why. Any advice will be helpful

Comment: `parseInt('false')` gives `NaN`, not `false`

Comment: Thanks. How I can fix this. Maybe my brain is dying now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just check the string, to either be "true" or "false", then set a boolean variable that mirrors that:

```
var showScrollWheel = false;

if (scriptParams.option_Scroll == "true") {
   showScrollWheel = true;
}
```

Then use that variable to pass into the map options:

```
scrollwheel: showScrollWheel
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was really stupid enough to miss that simple thing. Really I think I need some rest. Thanks once again.